# Validation call according Checkbox check in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have one checkbox and two input fields I want if I check checkbox then second (b) input box is require otherwise first (a) input field in require.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="try" id="try" value="on">

<input type="text" name="a" id="a">
<input type="text" name="b" id="b">



$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'a' => 'nullable|required_if:try,off',
    'b' => 'nullable|required_if:try,on'
]);
```

Try but not success. Please Help. Edit [Typo in required_if]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define rule on try input like :

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'a' => 'partialARequired',
    'b' => 'partialBRequired'
 ]);
```

Then you must define your partialRequired method's definition:

```
class customValidation extends Validator
{

    public function validatePartialARequired($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if(!in_array('try',$this->data) && empty($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function validatePartialBRequired($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if(in_array('try',$this->data) && empty($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```